# Only getting query terms as highlighted results with lucene highlighter (3.0)

Tags: c#, search, lucene, lucene.net

I'm using the current code to get fragments to highlight on lucene output, but the results are always just the searched for string.

```
var parser = new MultiFieldQueryParser(new[] { "contents", "PageName" }, 
    new StandardAnalyzer());                   
Query query = parser.Parse(Query);

QueryScorer scorer = new QueryScorer(query);
Formatter formatter = new SimpleHTMLFormatter(config.HighlightFormatterPrefix,
    config.HighlightFormatterSuffix);
Highlighter highlighter = new Highlighter(formatter, scorer);
highlighter.SetTextFragmenter(new SimpleFragmenter(100));
TokenStream stream = new StandardAnalyzer().TokenStream("contents",
    new StringReader(Query));
return highlighter.GetBestFragments(stream, Query, 2, ".");
```

In case it is helpful, here is the code used for the query:

```
var parser = new MultiFieldQueryParser(new[]{"contents","PageName"}, 
    new StandardAnalyzer());
Query query = parser.Parse(searchString);

Hits results = searcher.Search(query);
var hits = new List<LuceneSearchResult>();
for (int index = 0; index < results.Length(); index++)
{
    Document document = results.Doc(index);

    var searchResult = new LuceneSearchResult();
    searchResult.Document = document;
    searchResult.Query = searchString;
    searchResult.Id = document.GetField("ID").StringValue();
    searchResult.Score = results.Score(index);
    hits.Add(searchResult);
}
```

Whatever I search for is the exact same as the string that is returned for the highlighted fragments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue.  The resulting working code was a change in the results:

```
var parser = new QueryParser("contents", new StandardAnalyzer());
Query query = parser.Parse(Query);
SimpleHTMLFormatter formatter = new SimpleHTMLFormatter(config.HighlightFormatterPrefix, config.HighlightFormatterSuffix);
QueryScorer fragmentScorer = new QueryScorer(query,"contents");
Highlighter highlighter = new Highlighter(formatter, fragmentScorer);
highlighter.SetTextFragmenter(new SimpleFragmenter(100));
TokenStream tokenStream = new SimpleAnalyzer().TokenStream(config.MainContentFieldName, new StringReader(field.StringValue()));

return highlighter.GetBestFragments(tokenStream, field.StringValue(), 2, ".");
```

I changed from multiple fields to a single field on the query since the pagename would never be useful in the summary this is being used for and changed from a Formatter to a SimpleFormatter